# Highcharts: Dynamically add series value to category name

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Working with a simple highcharts bar graph such as so: http://jsfiddle.net/bvuWR/106/

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#updateAxis").click(function(){
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Lemon']);
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++)
        {
            chart.series[i].addPoint(Math.random() * 5, true, true);
        }
    });

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            reversed: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });        
});
```

});

Is there any way that I can grab data passed as a data series and add under the category?

This example has the data hardcoded in the config, however, I'll be passing the values to the data series dynamically and the value in the category would need to change as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set axis type as category and define categories from points names.

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [{
      y: 5,
      name: 'Apples'
    }, {
      y: 2,
      name: 'Oranges'
    }, {
      y: 3,
      name: 'Pears'
    }]
  }]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d41cvheL/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories